# Calculating Perpendicular Vectors from a single Look Vector

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

I have one vector that represents a 'look' direction. I need to calculate the 'right' direction and the 'up' direction. Say I have the vector( 0.79, -0.58, 0.188 ), I thought I could compute cross product between 'look' and 'up( 0,1,0 )' to get the 'right' vector and then cross 'right' and 'look' to get the true 'up' but it is incorrect. What method do I use to accurately compute the 'right' and 'up' vectors using the 'look' vector?

Comment: Problem seems to be that a look direction is insufficient to determine the right and up directions (assuming you mean the local up and right of the looker), as the 'looker' can rotate about the axis of the look direction. For example: I could be looking in direction (0,0,1), with my right being (1,0,0) and my up being (0,1,0). If I rotate about the z axis 90 degrees, now my up has rotated to (1,0,0) and my right to (0,-1,0). So you need an extra normal to, for example, determine the orientation of your up.

Comment: @Mike I'm using directx, typically the right vector is found using the cross prod of the look and up( 0, 1, 0 ) vectors, then the up vector is found using the cross of right and look...however, the cross product of look and up does not always yield the correct right vector...how can I compute the correct right vector using look and up( 0,1,0 )?

Comment: Is it sometimes right and sometimes wrong? I could certainly see a problem if your look was coincidentally equal to (0,1,0).

Comment: i found a solution by calculating the yaw and pitch angles of the look vector( from identity: 0, 0, 1 ), creating a rotation matrix from those angles and transforming the right identity vector( 1, 0, 0 ) by that rotation matrix...this produces a vector exactly 90degrees to the right of the look vector...